# Auto configuration and manual configuration of apache camel routes simultaneously

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have a list of camel routes and their configuration in json files. These routes needs to be configured manually based on the configuration present. I have created camel context instance and manually added the routes once the configuration is done successfully. This works fine until I add another route another route but this time it is meant to be configured automatically and does not required any configuration.

This is where I am stuck. Spring does not configure this automatically until I add it to the camel context manually. If I do not call the method that adds the routes to camel context then spring auto configures this new route.

What should be done here? I need to auto configure this new route only after all the other manually configured routes are configured.

Let see how manually added routes are created-

I have created an AbstractRouter class which extends the RouteBuilder class. All this class does is set the configuration in a map that the classes that extend this will use.

```
public abstract class AbstractRouter extends RouteBuilder {
    private final Map<String, Object> configMap;
}
```

In my main class I have a method addRoute that takes the configuration from db and add the spring component (that extends the abstractRouter) to the camel context.

```
public void runService(id) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> configurations = this.configRepository.retrieveConfigurations(id);
    this.addRoute(configMap);
    this.camelContext.start();
}

public void addRoute(Map<String, Object> configMap) {
    String className = (String)configMap.get("componentClass");
    Constructor<?> constructor = Class.forName(className).getConstructor(Map.class);
    AbstractRouter component = (AbstractRouter)constructor.newInstance(configMap);
    component.validateConfig();
    this.camelContext.addRoutes(component);
}
```

Here we create an instance of the component(route) and add to camel context. I have created another class TestComponent which has to be configured only after all the routes are added manually.

```
@Component
@DependsOn({"applicationMain"})
public class TestConsumer extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // all the camel routes
    }
}
```

As mentioned earlier, this only works if I remove the manual addition of routes to camel context. Or if I add this route manually just before starting the camel context.

camel.bom.version => 3.20.2
spring.boot.version => 2.7.8

How to overcome this situation?